# Preciso fazer um select de quais funcionarios estão alocados em quais projetos

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

Preciso fazer um select de quais funcionarios estão alocados em quais projetos mas quando rodo meu código:

```
select projeto.nome, funcionario.nome from projeto, funcionario
```

ele seleciona todos os nomes em todos os projetos e não como estão realmente alocados. Como posso refinar essa pesquisa?

edit:
estao organizados a seguir em 3 tabelas:
alocacao.

[image: alocacao]

funcionario

[image: funcionario]

e projeto

[image: projeto]

se faltar algo por favor, podem pedir, comecei faz pouco tempo em mysql.

Comment: Sem as estruturas das tabelas fica impossível sugerir alguma consulta.

Comment: Boa tarde rafael, primeiramente bem vindo à comunidade, recomendo que você faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e dê uma olhada na seção [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Rafael, ja resolveu seu problema?o que você quer é escolher num combo, como seria esse combo? O combo vai ter o nome do projeto?, nome do funcionario?ou o tempo , usado?, ou o que você quer na realidade, é um select mostrando o nome do funcionario + projeto + tempo?

Answer (score 1):

Solução é mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT projeto.nome, func.nome FROM tbProjeto as projeto
LEFT JOIN funcionario as func ON func.codFunc = projeto.codFunc
```

Comment: Mais ou menos por que como os caras citaram acima você não passou as estruturas de suas tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

Se trata de duas tabelas correto ? 
Neste caso tente o seguinte:

```
select projeto.nome, funcionario.nome from projeto
join funcionario
    on funcionario.id = projeto.funcionario
```

Verifique as relações entre as tabelas pois este é somente um exemplo.